# If I remove a CPU then put it back in is that harmful?

Tags: cpu

If I take out my cpu and then put it back in, even after the system has been used, will that damage or change anything?

Comment: Not if you know what you're doing. If you don't, I wouldn't try.

Comment: Learn about esd precautions, Desco have some wonderful YT videos. Learn how to fit chips correctly, pay attention to pressures, cooling equipment and thermal paste.

Comment: If you do it 'wrong' you might bend pins.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek my CPU is intel so it doesn’t have pins

Comment: For me if you ask such question mean you have no experience in the area. So do not do it. Also I do not see the reason behind your question.

Comment: @RomeoNinov yeah I don’t have much experience, however this question is in case I have to transfer cpu to a different pc or motherboard

Comment: Your motherboard does. They can get bent too. Its happened to me before

Comment: *"CPU is intel so it doesn’t have pins"* pins are in the chip or the socket… damaging either is not a good start. Lots of pictures of people who dropped a screwdriver or the chip itself in the socket whilst fumbling…

Comment: You also have to watch out you get your thermal paste right, or you'll fry it...

Comment: they are surprisingly delicate. I am not sure if I bent a couple of pins just by removing and reinserting the CPU (LGA 1151) without the correct tool (which applies even pressure). (That motherboard was dead anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, carrying out firmly and accurately, you won't break anything. This is what people do in computer stores and services all the day; this is not a rocket science and does not require surgical accuracy.

Use standard safety rules for working with sensitive electronics: completely disconnect any power from the computer and discharge capacitors, wear the ESD drag chain, read and follow motherboard manual for CPU and heatsink installation/removal instructions, don't let any dirt and garbage to go into the socket or CPU contact pads. It would be extremely hard to clean afterwards.

That the question arose means you don't have an experience with this, though. I think everyone had broken a few components in their lives. So if you need this computer, don't do this just for fun, for no reason, or be prepared to break it. Train yourself on some old garbage, which will not be a pity to throw away if it breaks.